# Using Yii ActiveRecord to do the following query

Tags: database, activerecord, yii, frameworks

I have a table which I would like to get all the points as SUM() for a single user_id

e.g

```
tblPoints
user_id    points    
111          50
111          100
111          100
```

How would I use the $criteria = new CDbCriteria() function to get the SUM(points) for the user_id of '111' - with the result being 250.

So far I have this... how would I make add SUM clause?

```
$Criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$Criteria->condition = "user_id = 2342312";
$Products = ShopPurchases::model()->find($Criteria);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$criteria->select = array('*', 'SUM(points) as pointsSum');
```

Need to define $pointsSum as a public property in your model and use:

```
$Products->pointsSum
```